# Amazon Cassandra connection timeout on EC2 instance (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I cannot connect to Amazon managed Cassandra (Keyspaces) from my EC2 instance. The EC2 instance is in a private subnet of a VPC with a VPC endpoint for Keyspaces.

EC2 outbound rules:

```
All TCP 0.0.0.0/0
```

VPC Endpoint inbound rules:

```
Custom TCP  TCP 9142    0.0.0.0/0
```

VPC Endpoint outbound rules:

```
Custom TCP  TCP 9142    0.0.0.0/0
```

These rules might actually be too permissive.

C# driver error:

```
Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 
  All hosts tried for query failed (tried 10.16.192.201:9142: 
    TimeoutException 'The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of SSL authentication operation.'; 10.16.224.203:9142: 
      TimeoutException 'The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of SSL authentication operation.')
```

I can SSH into the EC2.

The DNS seems correct:

```sh
$ nslookup cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com 
Server:     10.16.0.2
Address:    10.16.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.16.192.201
Name:   cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.16.224.203
```

I cannot curl the endpoint (timeout):

```sh
$ curl cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:9142
```

And Telnet:

```sh
$ sudo yum -y install telnet

$ telnet cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com 
Trying 10.16.192.201...
^C 

# Gave up after 60s
```

The security group for the VPC endpoint allows `9142` traffic to/from anywhere. The security group for the EC2 instance allows egress to anywhere.

How can I connect to Cassandra?

---

**Update**

Adding the VPC endpoint to the public subnet I can now do:

```sh
$ telnet cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com 9142
Trying 10.16.224.203...
Connected to cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

---

**Update**

I *can* connect if the certificate revocation check is disabled.

```ml
sslOptions.SetCertificateRevocationCheck false
```

This makes me think that the issue is the connectivity from the EC2 to wherever the CRL is hosted. However, I don't want to move my EC2 to a public VPC, so what is a good strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a key to connect to `Cassandra` as per the documentation [Using a Cassandra .NET Core Client Driver to Access Amazon Keyspaces Programmatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_dotnetcore_driver.html)

```cs
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem","path_to_file\AmazonRootCA1.pem")
```

Comment: My application code does use a downloaded Amazon certificate

Comment: at least that explains the behavior for `curl` command. Can you try `telnet` to the endpoint?

Comment: `telnet` does not connect

Comment: that's a networking issue then. can you check the security group attached to your instance and your Cassandra deployment? Both `ingress and egress` rules for allowing the port you are trying to connect?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: After some tweaks I can get `telnet` to connect

Answer (score 0):

You can use private interface VPC endpoints to connect to keyspaces. This will allow you to use a different endpoint that's only accessible from a vpc so that network traffic does not leave the Amazon network.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/vpc-endpoints.html